# Laravel server won't start, error: "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string"

Tags: laravel

When I start my Laravel server, I get the error below:

> "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-10 08:44:12.-240929) at position 25 (2): Unexpected character"

What am I doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate app key, write in console:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

The "right" way defining default datetimes

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2014-06-23');
```

A Hack using pages.dateformat.default: 'm-d-Y'`

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '06-23-2014');
```